# Moving a Domain Controller from 2012 R2 to Another 2012 R2 on the Same network

Tags: windows, domain-controller

I would like to move all domain roles from my existing domain controller to another 2012 server on my network. How do I do this?

Comment: What do you mean by "domain rules"?  If I understand your requirement correctly, the usual way is to build a second domain controller in the domain, let it sync, migrate DHCP & DNS to the new DC, move the FSMO roles, and then demote the old DC.

Answer (score 4):

Yep, promote a fresh one. Don't move domain controllers. It's too easy to create a split brain condition when doing so, and it's simply easier to set up a fresh one. All you have to do is install the roles on your new box, and when doing so (in the wizard), say that you're adding a domain controller to an existing domain in an existing forest by specifying the name of your domain in that portion of setup.

Follow this guide to add a new controller if you feel lost: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/canitpro/2013/05/05/step-by-step-adding-a-windows-server-2012-domain-controller-to-an-existing-windows-server-2003-network/

After this is done, you may demote the domain controller you wish to retire. In previous versions, this was done using a single dcpromo command. Microsoft deprecated that command, and you can either do this by using the add/remove features wizard, or by using PowerShell. Awesome. So essentially, you're just wading through another wizard.

This guide is way better than the one on technet:
http://blogs.interfacett.com/how-to-demote-a-domain-controller-dc-in-windows-server-2012-active-directory-domain-services-ad-ds

Answer (score 2):

Add the necessary roles (AD DS and DNS), then promote the server as a new Domain Controller in an existing domain. Configure the DNS client settings on all domain members accordingly.

Comment: Also update DHCP to include the IP of the new DNS server(s).

Comment: So basically Just configure it as a fresh domain controller and promote it? Is there a guide to do this? Would I configure the DNS to point to old controller sorry first time doing a migration like this..